# Form submission not saving on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp

I have this project that saved just fine when I used Chrome or IE but when I used Firefox it appeared to stop working when I submitted a form.  I use a SchedulesController, call edit_member, and I used JsHelper to call another action, edit_test.  In edit_test, I used JsHelper to submit the form.

edit_member view file:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Schedule', array('id'=>"ScheduleEditMemberForm", 'action' => 'edit_member',$id,'default' => false));
        $data = $this->Js->get("#ScheduleEditMemberForm")->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
        $this->Js->get("#ScheduleEditMemberForm")->event(
            'submit',
            $this->Js->request(
                array('action' => 'edit_test',$id,$userId),
                    array(
                        'update' => '#s',
                        'data' => $data,
                        'async' => true,    
                        'dataExpression'=>true,
                        'method' => 'POST',

                    )
                )
        );
    echo $this->Form->input('dates', 
        array(
            'id'=>'datepicker',
            'type'=>'text',
            'label' => 'Work Date',                    
        ));
    echo $this->Form->end('Start');
```

edit_test

```
$data = $this->Js->get("#ScheduleEditTestForm")->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
    $this->Js->get("#ScheduleEditTestForm")->event(
            'submit',
            $this->Js->request(
                array('action' => 'compute',$id,$userId),
                    array(
                        'update' => '#s',
                        'data' => $data,
                        'async' => true,    
                        'dataExpression'=>true,
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'div' => false
                    )
                )
        );
    echo $this->Form->create('Schedule', array('action' => 'edit_test',$id,$userId));
```

In edit_test, I'm calling compute action to save data on the database, but I don't know why it can't save when using Firefox.  I also added this on my view file:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

I hope someone knows about this situation, and can help me.

CakePHP 2.

Comment: Got any feedback from Firebug?

Comment: what kind of feedback from firebug? sorry im not familiar with firebug.. is it possible that my error is the way i placed my form on the div i created?

Comment: From what I can see, your code creates an ajax request after creating a form. You mention it works on other browsers, and doesn't in FireFox - it would be very beneficial to see any feedback you may have from Javascript, that's all!

Comment: I think its better to also put the generated script from the helper. It should not be cakePHP problem but JS problem. JS helper is merely create javascript from the helper

Comment: this is from firebug, under console,response.
<form action="/trk/schedules/edit_test" 263="263" 92="92" id="ScheduleEditTestForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>    </div>

Comment: Thanks for response! Do you have any errors or anything?

Comment: hey, i know now the problem. its really the div. i placed the $this->Form->create() inside a div. and some input where in the block(which is floating). anyway, once i edited it placed it accordingly, its now working on all browser.
thanks for all the comments